# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError using Joda Time in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jodatime, noclassdeffounderror

I have a project created in Eclipse and I installed joda-time-2.3 in Eclipse, following these steps:

1. Download Joda Time
2. In Eclipse look for your project at package explorer and right click on it then call it New -> Folder -> libs.
3. Copy (or) drag & drop the joda-time-2.3.jar into the newly created libs folder.
4. Right click on your project again (in package explorer) then Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jars -> joda-time-2.3.jar.

After trying to run the code

```
67. ResultSet rs1 = dbm.ExecuteResultSet("SELECT * FROM Persons");
68.     while (rs1.next()){
        ...
77.    DateTime birth = new DateTime(rs1.getTimestamp("birth_date"));
78.    sb.append(date_format.format(birth));}
```

I get the error 
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/DateTime
    com.customerrelationshipmanager.servlets.test.doGet(test.java:77)"

I have imported "org.joda.time.DateTime". 
I noticed that the source for the jar was not defined, so I manually linked the source, although I understood that it shouldn't be necessary. 
I did this: "Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export"
I have cleaned the project and rebuilt.
I tried to replce the code with:
`DateTime birth = new DateTime(rs1.getTimestamp("birth_date").getTime());`

None of these worked. Please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Thanks,
Lau

Comment: Try copying the jar inside WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: I tried, but with no effect. It seems it was the launch configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Which is odd. Every third party library in your applications should be in WEB-INF/lib, or are you using a tool like maven to generate your war?

Comment: No, i am not using any other tool. Just Eclipse as IDE. So if it has anything built in, than I am. However, I have added the libs folder under the project, as described above, and afterwards I built the path to the jar located there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is on the classpath when you compile, but not when you run. Check your launch configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ykaganovich. This solved the issue. Now I have a new one, but on next line. :) So I guess this topic is closed. Thanks again!